# How do I erase (make transparent) one custom region in a Android's canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview

I'm overriding Android's ImageView in order to make the corners of my image transparent. I can accomplish that clipping the canvas in my onDraw(Canvas canvas):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path clipPath = new Path();
    int w = this.getWidth();
    int h = this.getHeight();
    clipPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,w,h), 10.0f, 10.0f, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to antialias this round rectangle, and the result are ugly corners like this:

[image]

I know I can clear parts of my canvas with antialiasing using `Paint` and `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`, what I don't know is to specify the round corners as the region to be erased. I'm looking for something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //superclass will draw the bitmap accordingly 
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    //this will erase a round rectangle, I need the exact inverse
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, rx, ry, paint);
}
```

Is there any way to "erase" not the round rectangle, but it's inverse, ie, the round corners? And what if I just want to erase one of the corners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw using a BitmapShader with a transparent color for your Paint object.
If you just want to erase one of the corners, try drawing it as a Path instead of a RoundRect.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(<original drawable>, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(0xFF000000);
    paint.setShader(bitmapShader);

    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, rx, ry, paint);

}
```

Comment: But should I draw the actual original drawable in my onDraw()? I see in android source code that the [ImageView's onDraw()](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java) performs different kinds of checks and canvas modifications (ex: for padding).

Comment: You draw your original drawable as the BitmapShader. The area that is outside of your rounded rect will be drawn with transparent instead.

Comment: The first parameter of `BitmapShader` is not a drawable but a bitmap instead.